# File uploading using PHP

Tags: php, html

i want to upload the file and save it to uploads folder in our directory.
i have done that by using that code..
but its not working..here is an error..

"Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1341221475::1aaaa.text): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/PHP/upload_file.php on line 24 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpSZhm3c' to 'uploads/1341221475::1aaaa.text' in /var/www/html/PHP/upload_file.php on line 24 Stored in: aaaa/aaaa.text"

please help

code :

```
            if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "ERROR ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "NAME : ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br>";
                echo "TYPE : ".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."<br>";
                echo "SIZE : ".($_FILES["file"]["size"]/1024)."KB<br>";
                echo "Stored in : ".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."<br>";
                if (file_exists("aaaa/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                      {
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                      }
                else
                      {
                $target_path = "uploads/";
                    $target_path = $target_path . time() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
                      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target_path);
                      echo "Stored in: " . "aaaa/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                      }
            }
```

Comment: Simply Give permissions to the folder !

Comment: If you're running linux chmod it. Its a simple permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is running under a certain user (for example, "www"). Make sure that user has write access to the uploads folder.

Comment: Your web server is unlikely to be running as root. For example, if you're using Apache, you start it as root, and it'll spawn off a process under a different user (such as "www".)

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to Apache (for example) as Owner of your output directory, it will then be able to create files.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write a file using code, the user that is running the code should have permission. In this case whoever started the apache webserver should have permission to write in that folder. Use chmod command to specify permissions.

In case you are not worried about security much, you can just provide 777 to the uploads folder like this. Assuming your uploads folder is in /var/www/html/site/uploads, then run

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/site/uploads
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

make sure your uploads folder has a full permission so that you can move your files into it.

try `chmod 777 -R` to the uploads directory. For example:

```
 $ sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/PHP/uploads/
```